Azure App Service Deployment Issue;The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable
I get this error "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." anytime I try to access my dotnet 8.0 core app deployed on azure service. Also deployment is always successful, and there are no credentials in the app to be fetched froma appsettings.
I'm using the zip approach and here is my cli:
az webapp deploy --resource-group rg-cecurechat-prod-eastus --src-path DallEAPIService.zip --name TestingDalle


Using the cli command: az webapp deploy --resource-group rg-cecurechat-prod-eastus --src-path DallEAPIService.zip --name TestingDalle

Check the Kudu console. Based on the file structure, update the path mappings in the configuration section of the Azure Web App.

I created a sample ASP.NET Core 8 MVC application and deployed it to Azure using the following command for ZIP deployment.
az webapp deploy --resource-group <AzureResourceGroupName> --name <AzureWebAppName> --slot <SlotName> --src-path <ZipFilePath>

Even I got the same error, so I checked the Kudu files and found that my application is saved under the  wwwroot/WebApplication7  folder.


Then I updated the path mapping in the configuration section of the Azure Web App, changing it from  site\wwwroot  to  site\wwwroot\WebApplication7.

Make sure that the  web.config  file is added to the root directory of the application. Additionally, copy all the  .dll  files and other files from the  bin  folder to the main folder.
web.config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<location  path="."  inheritInChildApplications="false">
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
<add  name="aspNetCore"  path="*"  verb="*"  modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2"  resourceType="Unspecified"  />
</handlers>
<aspNetCore  processPath="dotnet"  arguments=".\<ApplicationName>.dll"  stdoutLogEnabled="false"  stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout"  hostingModel="inprocess"  />
</system.webServer>
</location>
</configuration>


Azure Output:

